# Como simular um contra-relógio com tkinter?

Tags: python

Estou a desenvolver um jogo em python "Quem quer ser milionário" e queria meter no jogo o modo "contra-relógio" a aparecer o tempo enquanto respondemos à pergunta e quando o tempo acabar e a pergunta nao tiver sido respondida o programa termina "game over"

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo abaixo faz uma contagem regressiva de 60 segundos ao final desse tempo é exibido uma mensagem. Para isso funcionar é utilizado o método [`after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) disponível no [Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/), esse método registra uma função [*callback*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback) que será chamada após um determinado momento, uma única vez, para continuar chamando esse *callback* você precisa registra-lo novamente dentro de si para atualizar a exibição do tempo restante.

O Tkinter só garante que o *callback* não seja chamado antes do previsto, se o sistema estiver ocupado, poderá haver um atraso maior.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter as tk

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.wm_title("Quem quer ser um milionario")
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", width=40, height=5)
        self.label.pack()
        self.remaining = 0
        self.countdown(60) # Em segundos

    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.label.configure(text="Game Over")
            # O tempo esgotou, fazer terminar o programa aqui
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

<sub>[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599462/1608936)</sub>

Não deve ser difícil implementar essa lógica, você pode criar uma variável *booleana* inicializada como falso, se o usuário responder a pergunta você altera o estado da variável para verdadeira. Veja um exemplo:

```
answered = False
...
..

if self.remaining <= 0 and answered == False:
    self.label.configure(text="Game Over")
    # O tempo esgotou, fazer terminar o programa aqui
```

Comment: pessoal obrigado resultou na perfeição :D